# F# Functions (forward pipe operator) does not work with arrays?

Tags: f#

I have a complex example but I reduced the case using simple obejcts.

Given 2 functions:

```ml
let add (a:int)   b = a     + b
let aee (a:int[]) b = a.[0] + b
```

them can be used in this way:

```ml
let c = add 1 5 

let a = [|1; 2|]
let d = aee a 5
```

So, why this is valid:

```ml
let c = 1 |> add 5
```

and this is not ?

```ml
let d = [|1;2|] |> aee 5  // Type mismatch, expecting int[] -> `a but given int -> int
```

My real scenario, in case it matters, is the following:

```ml
open FSUnit

type Tick (symbol:string, ask:decimal, bid:decimal) =
    member __.Symbol = symbol
    member __.Ask = ask
    member __.Bid = bid

let containSymbol (ticks:Tick[]) symbol =
    ( ticks |> Array.tryFind (fun t -> t.Symbol = symbol) ).IsSome


let ticks = [| Tick("aaa", 1m, 2m) |]

// I'm able to do these
should be True <| containSymbol ticks "aaa" 
containSymbol ticks "aaa" |> should be True

// but not this
ticks |> containSymbol CurrencyPair.XRP_BTC |> should be True  // does not work as described in the small example
// or (desiderable) this
ticks |> should contain (fun t -> t.symbol = "aaa")           // don't know how to create/pass a ContainwsConstraint with a function
```

Yes, the final goal is to be able to use `ticks |> should contain (fun t -> t.symbol = "aaa")` but I'm going with the first little step...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe operator allows you to pass an argument into a function which may or may not have been partially evaluated.　The value being piped in is passed as the *next* argument to that function.

In this example:

```
let d = [|1;2|] |> aee 5
```

You are partially evaluating `aee` with the argument `5`, and then passing in the argument `[|1;2|]` after that, using the pipe operator, but this does not work, because the first parameter of `aee` is an array, not an integer.

In order for this to work the way you are trying it, you need to change the order of the parameters:

```
let aee b (a:int[]) = a.[0] + b 
let d = [|1;2|] |> aee 5
```